# npm install connect-redis errors finding debug@ ^1.0.4 ... but I have version 2.0.0... why?

Tags: node.js, npm

I expect the symbol '^' to indicate that debug version 1.0.4 or higher required. If I am correct, npm install connect-redis should find debug@2.0.0 that is installed globally on my system. I have node version 0.6.12 installed and npm -v 1.1.4.

Here is the error message:

```
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: debug@'^1.0.4'
```

Here is a list of the globally installed packages:

```
├── async@0.9.0
├─┬ debug@2.0.0
│ └── ms@0.6.2
├─┬ passport-local@1.0.0
│ └── passport-strategy@1.0.0
├─┬ restify@1.4.4
│ ├── async@0.1.22
│ ├── bunyan@0.10.0
│ ├── byline@2.0.2
│ ├── dtrace-provider@0.0.9
│ ├── formidable@1.0.11
│ ├─┬ http-signature@0.9.9
│ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ └── ctype@0.5.0
│ ├── lru-cache@1.1.0
│ ├── mime@1.2.5
│ ├── node-uuid@1.3.3
│ ├── qs@0.5.0
│ ├── retry@0.6.0
│ └── semver@1.0.14
└─┬ ws@0.4.32
  ├── commander@2.1.0
  ├── nan@1.0.0
  ├── options@0.0.6
  └── tinycolor@0.0.1
```

I don't really want to install an older version of debug if not necessary. Please advise :)

Comment: What node version do you have installed?

Comment: I have node -v 0.6.12 installed - i edited the question to reflect that - thanks for helping me get my question right...

Comment: @Reinsbrain this is a very old version of node ... what version of npm do you have?

Comment: npm -v 1.1.4 - editing the question to reflect that. My node version might have some effect in this case but it seems unlikely. Re: old node... is that not the latest stable? I just installed it recently after doing apt-get update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your version of npm does not understand the semver `^` operator for module version matching. You should consider upgrading to the latest stable version of node (v0.10.32 as of this writing) and you will also get the latest stable version of npm which supports that operator.

Comment: this looks like the solution - im going to try that right now and get back to you on this...

Comment: hmm, looks like i have to do it from ppa... i updated apt_get which thinks my oversion 0.6.2 is the latest stable...

Comment: had to update apt-get repository: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js to get later version of node... now resolves problem

Comment: Yes, using that PPA or building from source are the best ways to make sure you are up to date with the latest stable version. Distro repos typically fall behind pretty quickly.